# JPA/Hibernate callback for autocommits

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'd like to intercept each event in which an entity is about to be stored in the database. According to http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event I can do that using all @Pre... annotations. It's working, but only when the transaction is being commited when it ends. If a flush happens before a transaction ends, none of the callbacks are triggered.

Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a config issue or bug, as the prePersist, PreUpdate and PreRemove should happen before the event in question, so on the flush.  Which event in particular and under what situation have you been able to see this occur?

Comment: The problem is this is nothing triggered by me. I'm just trying to retrieve a new entity and hibernate auto-flushes some things that I'm working on. I need it to call those callbacks but it doesn't do it. Maybe the order is incorrect? I haven't mentioned but it crashes with javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of ... So maybe it crashes before any callback is ever executed...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event#Listeners_and_External_Callback_Methods_

If a callback method throws an exception within an active transaction, the transaction is marked for rollback and no more callback methods are invoked for that operation.

Seems like your callbacks are not called at all, since there is an Exception...